# Link Codeception Vendor Path with Linux

Tags: php, linux, codeception, vendor

Right now I have a project here:

/srv/www/web/src/private/protected

It has a /vendors/ folder with /codeception in it. I have to currently do:

./vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept run

How can I link this directory/command 'codecept' so I don't have to type the absolute path every time?

I want:

codecept run

Instead of:

./vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept run

Comment: you can concatenate it to `$PATH` environment variable. `PATH=$PATH:full_path_to_script`.

Comment: Editing /etc/environment to: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/srv/www/tigoweb/src/private/proceted/vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept"
 didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project folder you could

`ln -s vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept .`

to create a symlink in the current folder.

Comment: This will work only for running the script from the same directory not from other paths :)

Comment: Poor solution tbh. He'll have to do that for every project he's working on. See my solution below for a one off setup that will work in any of his projects.

Comment: "_Right now I have a project here_" OP didn't ask for a solution for all of his projects

Answer (score 0):

**concatenate it to $PATH environment variable**

```
PATH=$PATH:full_path_to_script
```

$PATH is an environment veritable used to find commands/scripts in wanted paths.

### each time you are looking for a script or command it looks at the Paths that are listed in this variable

see your paths with:

```
  ~> echo $PATH
```

Comment: Each time? That's typing even more. See my answer so you won't have to do this each time.

Comment: thanks. not each time. what you should do is to add this line to your ~/.aliases   or  ~/.bashrc file.   I have tried to explain the  main idea. any way, have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

I added a symbolic link like so:
sudo ln -s /srv/www/web/src/private/protected/vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept /usr/local/bin/codecept

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.bash_profile)`. Add the following:

`export PATH=$PATH:bin:vendor/bin`

This will allow you to run any executables in both the `bin/` and `vendor/bin` folders without having to `cd` into them.

You need to close and reopen your terminal for the change to take effect!

Comment: You could also `source ~/.bashrc` if you don't want to reopen your terminal